# Does Steam notify the user that they need Java for a game when they buy/download/install it?

Tags: java, steam

My mate and I are gonna make a game for Steam and I, as the programmer, want to use Java as that is my current favorite language. So I need to know, does Steam notify the user that they need Java for a game when they buy/download/install it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about a Steam feature than about game development.

Comment: Quite frankly, I would be upset if the game I bought forces me to install Java. It is a very powerful language and kudos to you for loving it but it's more of a hate-hate relationship for any average user that has to be exposed to Java. Expect inflammatory comments popping up on your game's store page which say things like "Virus simulator 2016" or "Do not install, it forces an outdated version of Java onto your machine."

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Which is precisely why things like this should be abstracted away from users -- they literally haven't a clue what they're talking about. Vulnerabilities were only in the web browser plugin (which never was a good idea). In any case, package your game up to include all resources necessary for it to run... don't assume the user has anything. Go the Minecraft route as an example, use launch4j or install4j to build a bundled installer/executable with the JRE baked in. No security vulnerabilities, and no hassle for the user.

Comment: Pack Java in with the game. A game tool I use called StarParse does this with its installation. It is annoying to have to download 40 MB the first time, but it removes the problems of managing Java JRE versions and such.

Comment: Some games install .NET for you upon first launch.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus "it forces an outdated version of Java onto your machine" is assuming too much intelligence from users writing reviews. And it's assuming they care in the first place.

Comment: @SnakeDoc That is an excellent suggestion and I definitely agree with it. The purpose of my comment was to make sure that OP stays as far away from the "notify the user that they need Java for a game when they buy/download/install it" route because that would be detrimental to the experience. The user don't care; run the installer and let me play my game!

Comment: @immibis You are right BUT it only takes one semi-educated user that had a bad Java virus experience from a shady website to post a comment which gets highly upvoted or get top "funny" status. If you've never heard an IT guy mutter "Java bad" like a caveman then you are an exception in this world. Also, asking the user to download something is suggesting a lot of user-affordance especially considering how many sites would try to dupe you into installing a virus rather than the real thing.

Comment: @SnakeDoc I'm a software engineer and I go out of my way to ensure I don't have that steaming, bloated pile installed on my machine. Intentionally trying to con your users because you're scared of how they'd react to transparency isn't the right way to go.

Comment: @Basic Then you haven't a clue about engineering, java, game development, or Steam for the matter. You cannot ship a game on steam that requires the user to go install some separate runtime on their own. Secondly, try to learn a little about the JVM and it's ecosystem before you let everyone know how uninformed you are. Lastly, bundling a runtime in your game is the standard, not the exception.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Care to try that again without the personal attacks? You are trying to present yourself as a professional, right?

Comment: @Basic Maybe try again without the "appeal to authority" argument out of the gates. "I'm an engineer... but I don't know what I'm talking about" is a rather funny way to tell someone they're wrong on a thread from 8 years ago... especially when you're throwing stones form a glass house of dotnet garbage. But, whatever, you've probably had to rewrite your app 6 times since posting due to incompatibilities...

Comment: @SnakeDoc Nice try, but _what_ appeal to authority? I have worked in the field for decades but you don't need to have that experience to see a language in decline... https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/java/. In any case, I don't think we're adding much value here, do you? All the best and have a pleasant weekend.

Comment: @Basic lol if you were as competent as you think you are you wouldn't need to tell people you're a software engineer. This is StackExchange, damn near everyone is a SE. But, by opening your ignorant mouth and telling the world how little you understand the field you only serve to demonstrate how isolated dotnet developers are. Drink more Microsoft Kool aid... and then rewrite your app again.

Answer (score 20):

To answer your question directly, no Steam doesn't notify the purchaser that the game needs Oracle's Java Runtime Environment installed to play the game. That's because there shouldn't be any need to, any game that has a dependency on the JRE will download and install it as part of the normal Steam installation procedure. This is no different than games that have dependencies on Microsoft's Visual Studio, DirectX or .NET runtime. There is even a standard [JRE depot](https://steamdb.info/depot/286241/) that you can use.

That said, I personally refuse to buy or install any game that dependent on Oracle's JRE. I don't want to have to deal with that nonsense. An alternative route would follow [Minecraft's lead](http://www.howtogeek.com/210907/minecraft-doesnt-need-java-installed-anymore-its-time-to-remove-it/) an include a Java VM as part of the game itself. That is, instead of installing a VM for all Java applications on the machine to use, like with the Oracle JRE, you install a VM side-by-side your game that only your game uses. I don't think you can do this with the Oracle JRE, I believe Minecraft uses one based on OpenJDK.

On the other hand, if you're just starting out, you should probably take the easy route and use the standard Oracle JRE install, and just accept some people won't like that.

Comment: +1 for the direct answer.
As an addendum, there's a list of alternative JVMs @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines

Answer (score 14):

*This is by no means an answer, but some points to consider. It did not fit in the comments box.*

I would think that even if you were to use c++, you would need to ship your game with a bunch of [Redistributable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003), at least on Windows. Unless you can manage to not use Visual Studio tools and such. I don't know what happens for Mac users.

And if you go with Java, I believe there would be a way to ship the JVM with your game. This would increase the download size, but it would ensure

1. that the client has a jvm, and
2. that the client has the *correct* jvm version for your game

Note that it is already necessary to ship the JVM with the game if you are distributing through the Mac App Store, so if you plan on distributing beyond Steam, this may be necessary anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did say to my mate when he asked about making it cross-platform that I'd probably have to remake it in C# for Mac users but it would be easier to make it in Java and hope that the user has Java. Do you think I'd be able to make it in Java but not include the JVM then have a thing in the program that tests whether they have Java or not?

Comment: Probably. I'm not that knowledgeable in that field though. I'd search a bit more the web. Perhaps [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79057/how-to-java-game-to-steam-greenlight) could be of interest to you.

Comment: @DreddTrekkiter As a suggestion, if you plan on porting it to C#/Mono for Mac users, just do the whole thing that way. Monogame might be a good option for you to look into.

Comment: Or just use C. It's fast, low-level and a pain to code graphical stuff in.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt You said "I believe there would be a way to ship the JVM with the game". It is absolutely possible. While not a game, I do it with my Java app using [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). I know that there are other tools out there that can do the same.

Comment: @DreddTrekkiter Why would you need to port it to C# for Mac users? You can submit a Java app to the Mac App Store so long as it includes the JVM. Oracle [provides documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) for doing this through Apache Ant, although I think there are better tools through Gradle.

Comment: Most Java vulnerabilities only concern java applets and when running untrusted code. If you download and run a game locally, you already (have to) trust that it won't do anything malicious. I don't think there is any more inherent risk in using java than there is in using any other framework/engine/technology.

Comment: kapep SnakeDoc I updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This [related question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79057/how-to-java-game-to-steam-greenlight) recommends using [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

Based on [3 Ring's code page](http://www.threerings.net/code/), it looks like they use [getdown](https://github.com/threerings/getdown/) for Spiral Knights.

You might consider reaching out to [Puppy Games](http://www.puppygames.net/) to see if they're willing to share any insights.  Similarly, there are some devs on [java-gaming.org](http://www.java-gaming.org/) that have some experience with this.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make your custom Java and put it inside the install EXE along with your JAR file to put it on steam.

Comment: This answer would be more useful to future readers if it described the specific steps to take to do that.