# How To Upload JavaScript Games To Steam

Tags: javascript, publishing, steam

So I've been making this game called [The Necromancer](https://ninja25538.github.io/Project) and (quick note, I am **still** working on the game. Also, I know this sounds similar to [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79057/how-to-java-game-to-steam-greenlight), but my question is for the general process) I wanted to publish on the Steam Store. However, I don't know what the process is, as in what you do to get your game posted on Steam. Also, how would I get a few files, and somehow put it in a virtual package that I can give to Steam. I just feel rather confused on the subject.

Thank you for your time

Comment: If you are no studio, you have to pass trough greenlight. Don't even waste your time to contact Valve. Read their site to know more about.

Comment: @DH thank you, though that felt slightly rude

Comment: fyi nothing is visible when I go to your game's link. There's a loading animation for a few seconds, and then a blank page.

Comment: @jhocking Checking the code, it appears that that's all that's been published as of the moment. In fact, 3 seconds is the hard-coded timeout for the content to be loaded, presumably because the content to load isn't large enough yet to test the loading script.

Comment: @jhocking I'll fix that, give me a bit

Comment: @jhocking, that's odd, it works on my Dell Chromebook, but on a Windows Nextbook, it didn't

Comment: Looking at both your page's source and the console, you appear to have 2 <body> tags, plus the code is looking for something called "myDiv" but nothing has that name. Did you even bother to look for errors in the browser? because both these errors were blaring bright red when I looked

Comment: I didn't notoce, it always worked fine

Comment: @jhocking And the second body tag is </body>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Steam only deals with downloadable games, not browser games, so you'll need to package your game using something like [nw.js](https://nwjs.io/) or [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/). Also you might want [this library](https://github.com/greenheartgames/greenworks) for integrating with Steamworks.

(note that the question you linked is about Java, not JavaScript, so the technical details are very different. if only I had a nickel for every person who thinks Java and JavaScript are in any way related...)

Comment: Thanks! And I know the difference, some people don't and I didn't want to get flagged since they thought it was the same thing

Comment: Also, do you have any JavaScript packagers for Chrome OS? I have a windows laptop but just wondering.

Answer (score 6):

The current (2/21/2017), general process as described on the [Greenlight FAQ](http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/about/?appid=765&section=faq):

> **Who should submit their games to Steam Greenlight? Is there another way to submit my game to Steam?**
>
> Steam Greenlight has replaced our previous submission process. Any developer or publisher who is new to Steam and interested in submitting their game to the platform should submit their game through Steam Greenlight.

However, Valve is planning on changing the Greenlight in the near future to [Steam Direct](http://steamcommunity.com/games/593110/announcements/detail/558846854614253751):

> **A better path for digital distribution**
>
> The next step in these improvements is to establish a new direct sign-up system for developers to put their games on Steam. This new path, which we’re calling “Steam Direct,” is targeted for Spring 2017 and will replace Steam Greenlight. We will ask new developers to complete a set of digital paperwork, personal or company verification, and tax documents similar to the process of applying for a bank account. Once set up, developers will pay a recoupable application fee for each new title they wish to distribute, which is intended to decrease the noise in the submission pipeline.

As pointed out in by @jhocking's answer, a JavaScript game has some additional technical complications that you'll need to deal with.