# How to publish WebXR game on Quest or Steam stores?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js, steam

I would like to develop a simple and small game for WebXR so that Quest, Index, etc. can play it. I would eventually like to be able to put it on the Quest store and Steam.

Is there a way to publish a WebXR game in those stores? Or would I have to compile it for Android/Windows as a native application?

I am a web developer and familiar with JavaScript, so I was planning to use three.js

Comment: Seems like a partial duplicate of [How To Upload JavaScript Games To Steam](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/137705/33287), though that only addresses the Steam aspect, not the Quest Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta has an official process for WebXR content & is covered on their documentation on [WebXR Workflow](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/web/webxr-workflow/):

> ### Publishing Your Experience
>
> A WebXR experience is just a normal web page, so it can be served online like any other site.
>
> Meta Quest Browser also features WebXR experiences on the New Tab Page. If you have created a WebXR experience that you’d want to get featured, see [the submissions guidelines page](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/web/browser-new-tab/).
>
> #### WebXR Submission Form
>
> After following the guidelines and confirming you meet the technical requirements, submit your experience with the [WebXR Submission form](https://go.facebookinc.com/submit.html) to be considered for the New Tab Page.

Their submissions guidelines (linked above) list both content guidelines, technical requirements and technical recommendations. I suggest familiarizing yourself with them *before* investing resources in development so as to maximize effort on things that meet their criteria. You should also note that the openly state meeting their criteria does not guarantee your experience will be featured.

They also have additional WebXR developer info here: [Get Started with Oculus Browser & WebXR](https://developer.oculus.com/webxr/).

Answer (score 0):

you can publish your game on heyvr.io. https://heyvr.io/publish
There you can also get a lot more information on how to do it and what tools you can use.

Also there are a lot of WebXR games you can try to get some impressions for your game.

They also have a Discord https://discord.gg/xdzBpmqj.
The founders and other developers are very responsive and happy to help.